# Django: distinct on a foreign key, then ordering

Tags: python, django, postgresql, distinct

I have two models, `Track` and `Pair`. Each `Pair` has a `track1`, `track2` and `popularity`. I'm trying to get an ordered list by popularity (descending) of pairs, with no two pairs having the same `track1`. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
lstPairs = Pair.objects.order_by('-popularity','track1__id').distinct('track1__id')[:iNumPairs].values_list('track1__id', 'track2__id', 'popularity')
```

This gave me the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

...so I tried this:

```
lstPairs = Pair.objects.order_by('-popularity','track1__id').distinct('popularity', 'track1__id')[:iNumPairs].values_list('track1__id', 'track2__id', 'popularity')
```

This gave me entries with duplicate `track1__id`s. Does anyone know of a way of solving this problem? I'm guessing I'll have to use `raw()` or something similar but I don't know how I'd approach a problem like this. I'm using PostgreSQL for the DB backend so `DISTINCT` should be supported.

Comment: You probably have to use raw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's clarify: `DISTINCT` is standard SQL, while `DISTINCT ON` is a PostgreSQL extension.

The error (`DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`) indicates, that you should fix your `ORDER BY` clause, not the `DISTINT ON` (if you do that, you'll end up with different results, like you already experienced).

> The [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within each DISTINCT ON group.

This will give you your expected results:

```
lstPairs = Pair.objects.order_by('track1__id','-popularity').distinct('track1__id')[:iNumPairs].values_list('track1__id', 'track2__id', 'popularity')
```

In SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (track1__id) track1__id, track2__id, popularity
FROM pairs
ORDER BY track1__id, popularity DESC
```

**But *probably* in a wrong order.**

If you want your original order, you can use a sub-query here:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (track1__id) track1__id, track2__id, popularity
  FROM pairs
  ORDER BY track1__id
  -- LIMIT here, if necessary
)
ORDER BY popularity DESC, track1__id
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up. I ended up iterating through the resulting list and removing duplicates there (in my case it doesn't matter if the resulting list is shorter than requested), but it's great to get an explanation of this use case. I wouldn't have thought something like this would be so obscure that your answer isn't anywhere else on SO!

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation on distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

First:

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply.

You dont' specify what is your database backend, if it is not PostrgreSQL you have no chance to make it work.

Second:

> When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order.

I think that you should use raw(), or get the entire list of Pairs ordered by popularity and then make the filtering by track1 uniqueness in Python.